# typescript: problems with angular.bind and map

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
  function parseValueFromComplexType(complexType, item) {
                return item[complexType];
            }
```

In order to bind the value complextype, i use angular.bind

```
let parseValueFromComplexTypeWithValue = angular.bind('', parseValueFromComplexType , config.complexType);
val.values = val.values.map(parseValueFromComplexTypeWithValue);
```

Now typescript complains:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => {}'.

What does the error mean and how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function accepts a function with three parameters, in this structure:

```
callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U
```

The `bind` function of angular **returns** a simple `Function` type:

```
bind(context: any, fn: Function, ...args: any[]): Function;
```

**The error say:** You can't put just a `Function` where a `callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U` is expected.

Another issue here is that you are trying to use angular `bind` in a very weird way... If you want to preserve the `this` just use an arrow function.

Maybe something (Much simpler) like this:

```
var complexType = 'str';
val.values = val.values.map((item, index, array) => item[complexType]);
```